# problemas com Tooltip em jQuery e css

Tags: jquery, css

```
Galera montei um sisteminha de Tooltip bem simples usando jQuery e css.
```

Eles esta apresentando o Tooltip padrão, quando fica com o mouse sobre ele. Isso ocorre apenas no IE, Safari e Chrome antigo.

olha a foto do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o código abaixo.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {

        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .html(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('fast');
    }, function () {

        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function (e) {

        // Get X Y coordinates
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY + -25;
        $('.tooltip').css({top: mousey, left: mousex});
    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #616161;
    background-color:#323232;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.tooltip::after{    
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -20px;
    top: 3px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="masterTooltip" title="bla,bla,bla,bla">qeqweqweqweqqw</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz alguns testes simulando o internet explorer mais antigo, e realmente vi o problema, fiz algumas alterações no seu código e desta maneira não ocorreu este bug. Eu parei de ficar manipulando o elemento DOM (inserindo e removendo o p.tooltip), ele ja esxiste lá com display none, e ao hover apenas da o fadeIn e no hoverout usei o hide para sumir imediatamente.

Pelo menos, em meus testes parou de aparecer este erro.

*OBS, alterei o valor de `var mousex = e.pageX + 20;`  `para var mousex = e.pageX + 25;`, pois com o valor 20, ao mover o mouse para a direita, o tooltip ficava piscando, provavelmente porque estava muito próximo ao after do `p` que é 20px à esquerda, então ele acabava entrando neste container e não disparando a função hover em masterTooltip.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {

        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('.tooltip').html(title).fadeIn('fast');
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').hide();
    }).mousemove(function (e) {

        // Get X Y coordinates
        var mousex = e.pageX + 30;
        var mousey = e.pageY + -25;
        $('.tooltip').css({top: mousey, left: mousex});
    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #616161;
    background-color:#323232;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.tooltip::after{    
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -20px;
    top: 3px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" class="masterTooltip" title="Teste Com Imagem"/>
<p class="masterTooltip" title="Teste com Texto">Teste com Texto</p>
<p class="tooltip"></p>
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Bom realmente o problema dele ficar piscando foi resolvido, porém o problema original continua, tenta colocar o title em uma imagem por exemplo.

Comment: Editei o post com o teste em imagem, aqui eu simulei os navegadores: Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10 e 11 com o meu Microsoft Edge, o seu exemplo fica com o problema citado nos navegadores IE 8 ao 10. Porém o teste com as correções que eu fiz não apresentaram o problema relatado. Poderia me falar qual o navegador que você está usando para visualizar o problema? Teste ele pelo "executar" aqui do StackOverflow. caso não de problemas e no seu código continue dando, temos que verificar mais a fundo o que poderia estar causando isto.

Comment: eu uso o safari

Comment: Testei com o safari em um mac, e funcionou normalmente, você chegou a testar diretamente aqui pela simulação de código do stack overflwo ou você colocou o script em seu site e testou por ele?

Comment: hahahahah, foi um erro meu aqui. desculpa. Seu código funcionou 100%. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.